# On the convergence of the function series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}x^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be a smooth real function defined around origin. Consider the series
$\hat{f}(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}x^n$.
If we differentiate term by term  the series, we get $\frac{d}{dx}\hat{f}(x)=0$.
Thus $\hat{f}(t)$ should be constant. But in fact we are not
allowed to differentiate term by term from a series.

Next, suppose that $f$ is a smooth periodic function with Fourier expansion $f(t)=\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty c_me^{im\omega t}.$ Then

\begin{eqnarray}\hat{f}(t)&=&\sum_n\sum_m\frac{(-1)^n(im\omega)^{n}}{n!}c_me^{im\omega
 t}t^n\nonumber\\&=&
\sum_m\sum_n(\frac{(-1)^n(im\omega)^{n}}{n!}t^n)c_me^{im\omega
 t}\nonumber\\&=& \sum_me^{-im\omega t}c_me^{im\omega
 t}\nonumber\\&=&\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}c_m\nonumber\\&=&f(0).\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
Thus again it seems that the series should convergence to a
constant. But in the above
we have exchanged the order of two infinite sums which  are not allowed.

If one calculates  the series for common functions; polynomials, sine, cosine and  exponential, will find that the series converges to constant $f(0)$. In fact one can show that if $f$ is analytic at origin then the series $\hat{f}$ is
convergent uniformly and absolutely to the constant $f(0)$.

About the function $f(x):=e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}},f(0)=0$ although, we do not know the convergence of the series but one can
show that if the series is convergent then its sum is constant.

The main questions:

1. Is there a smooth function $f$ which is not  analytic at origin
   and the series $\hat{f}$ is convergent in an interval around
   origin and the sum is the constant $f(0).$?
2. Is there a smooth function $f$ which is not  analytic at origin
   and the series $\hat{f}$ is convergent in an interval around
   origin and the sum is not constant.?
3. If we define a linear differential operator of infinite order
   $f\mapsto \hat{f}-f(0)$. Then in above we said that analytic
   functions at origin are contained in the space of eigenfunctions
   of the zero eigenvalue of this operator. Now the question arises
   that: are there nonzero eigenvalues for this operator?

Please see the preprint
arXiv:1105.2611v2 [math.GM] 5 Jun 2011 and the paper:  Journal of Applied Analysis, Volume 25, Issue 2, Pages 131–139, DOI: https://doi.org/10.1515/jaa-2019-0014.

Comment: This is a waaaaaaaay too long a question. My adice is to shorten a lot the preliminaries, only writing down the main results, and then choose one question to ask...or at most two. If there are more questions open a new thread.

Comment: I posted a shorten version.

Comment: Comment on the first paragraph: by the Taylor formula, $\hat f(x) = f(0)$.

Comment: Thanks Gary. But first of all we have not assumed that $f$ is analytic at $x$. Secondly, if even it is so, then the interval of convergence of Taylor series at center $x$ may not include origin. So your conclusion is not true. In fact there are examples of functions with divergence $\hat{f}$ everywhere, see the references mentioned earlier.